# Getting "no parse" from Prelude.read

Tags: haskell

I've just started Haskell, and I've been trying to make a simple Number data type, which has a single Int like so:

```
data Number
  = Num Int
  deriving (Read, Show)
```

I then tried to do `read "1234" :: Number` hoping that would give something like `Num 1234`, but I seem to be getting an "Exception: Prelude.read: no parse" instead. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instance you derive would give `read "Num 1234" = Num 1234`.

This is the behavior one expects for instances of `Read`, but if you really want a different behavior, you'll have to implement `read` for `Number` yourself (you can re-use `Int`'s, though).

Comment: +1 - @Sp3000 you should see this as some kind of inverse to `show`

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes a lot more sense